# How to pass the user selected value from radioGroup to a action?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a radio button group like this :

```
<g:radioGroup name="myGroup" values="[1,2,3]" value="1" >
<p><g:message code="${it.label}" />: ${it.radio}</p>
</g:radioGroup>
```

Lets say that this in view named `questions`. User will select any answer from this and he will click a button named `calculate`. Which will redirect him to another action named `calculate`. Now in this action, how come I get the user selected answer from `questions` page?

Actually I will be having 70+ question on `questions` view page. How do I manage those? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching your example the answer will be in the `myGroup` parameter:

```
def calculate() {
  def answer = params.myGroup
}
```

I suggest renaming `myGroup` to a more meaningful name such as "question" plus its index e.g. `question1`, `question2` etc. to differentiate between radio groups of questions. This enables you to iterate over all request parameters and assign answers accordingly:

```
def calculate() {
  def questions = ... //list of questions rendered previously
  questions.eachWithIndex { question, i ->
    question.answer = params["question$i"]
  }
}
```

Of course the question-answer assignment blocks depends on your specific logic/data model.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It's the code that I took from Grails doc for example purposes.

Comment: In your second code, the line `def questions = ... //list of questions rendered previously` I could understand that? What you mean by that?

Comment: I guessed that you iterated over a set of questions in questions.gsp. To assigned the according answers you'll need the same set of questions in your calculate-action. With "..rendered previously" I only meant the questions which where displayed in your view.